# Shuffle a pack of cards and distribute it among four players. You need to stop the game when someone has 4 hearts and say who is the winner

Tags: python, probability

I need to write a python code for Shuffle a pack of cards and distribute it among four players. You need to stop the game when someone has 4 hearts and say who is the winner. As im a beginner in python and finished it straight forward way. can anyone give me optimized way to code this ??. here is my try..

```
import random
colour=["Heart","Spade","Club","Diamond"] 
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"J","Q","K","A"] 
player1,player2,player3,player4=[],[],[],[]
shuffle=[{x:y} for x in colour for y in a ]
cnt=0
while len(shuffle)!=0:
    p1,p2,p3,p4=random.sample(population=shuffle,k=4) 

    i1=shuffle.index(p1)
    del shuffle[i1]
    i2=shuffle.index(p2)
    del shuffle[i2]
    i3=shuffle.index(p3)
    del shuffle[i3]
    i4=shuffle.index(p4)
    del shuffle[i4]

    if "Heart" in p1:
        player1.append(p1)
        if len(player1)>=4:
            print("player 1 is win ,heart cards are:",player1)
            break
    if "Heart" in p2:
        player2.append(p2)
        if len(player2)>=4:
            print("player 2 is win,heart cards are:",player2)
            break
    if "Heart" in p3:
        player3.append(p3)
        if len(player3)>=4:
            print("player 3 is win,heart cards are:",player3)
            break
    if "Heart" in p4:
        player4.append(p4)
        if len(player4)>=4:
            print("player 4 is win,heart cards are:",player4)
            break
```

Comment: Seems like the question is asking for a review of working code, as such https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better site than SO for that.

Comment: If this is for an assignment the code itself seems fine and the only nitpick is that it should say "Player 1 wins" instead of "is win".
If its a personal project you want improve then the code review site is the place to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deck has 52 cards. Shuffle them once. Deal one card to each player until the deck is empty or one of the players has 4 hearts. A heart is a card those number is 0 mod 4. the other suites are 1 mod 4, 2 mod 4, and 3 mod 4.

```
from random import shuffle

deck = range(52)
shuffle(deck)

from itertools import cycle

players = [[] for _ in range(4)]

for i, p in cycle(enumerate(players)):
    if not deck: break
    p.append(deck.pop())
    if sum(1 for c in p if c % 4 == 0) == 4:
        print i
        break

print players
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume card 1-12 are hearts. I used shuffle function to distribute the card and then broken them in 4 arrays. I am just counting the minimum index for the cards number less than 13 in each array and then returning the palyer index

```
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np
x = range(52)
shuffle(x)
x = [(i<13)*1 for i in x]
y = [np.cumsum([x[i*4+n] for i in range(13)]) for n in range(4)]
def findmin(x, v):
    try:
        return x.index(v)
    except:
        return 9999

y = [findmin(list(y[i]), 4)for i in range(4)]
y.index(min(y))
```